# What is execute list subquery

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite, I have

```
create tbl (id int, name text primary key);
create index tblIdIdx on tbl(id);
create tblAttributes (id int, name text, value numeric, primary key(id, name));
```

When I do

```
explain query plan select name, value from tblAttributes where sweepId = (select max(id) from tbl) and (name = 'n1' or name = 'n2' or name = 'n3');
```

I got the following results

```
 selectid    order   from  detail 
 "0"    "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE tblAttributes USING PRIMARY KEY (id=? AND name=?)"
 "0"    "0" "0" "EXECUTE SCALAR SUBQUERY 1"
 "1"    "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE tbl USING COVERING INDEX tblIdIdx"
 "0"    "0" "0" EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 2"
```

https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html explains that "EXECUTE SCALAR" is a cached query. What does EXECUTE LIST mean? Is it also cached?

Comment: There is a discussion on this: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/subquery-performance-td74631.html. In my case, does it mean "name = 'n1' or name = 'n2' or name = 'n3'" will call the subquery 3 times?